# How to solve Problem 3-39 in "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak? (Change of variable Theorem, Sard's Theorem)

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

I tried to solve Problem 3-39 but I could not solve it.

My attempt:
By Theorem 3-14, $g(B)$ has measure $0$.
Since $g$ in Theorem 3-13 is injective, I guess $B$ also has measure $0$.
If $B$ has measure $0$, then for almost all $x\in A$, $\det g'(x)\neq 0$.
I guess the following proposition holds:

> **3-13' Theorem.** Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $g:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a 1-1, continuously differentiable function such that $\det g'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in A-B$, where $B$ is a subset of $A$ which has measure $0$. If $f: g(A)\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then $$\int_{g(A)}f=\int_A(f\circ g)|\det g'|.$$

---

> **Problem 3-39.** Use Theorem 3-14 to prove Theorem 3-13 without the assumption $\det g'(x)\neq 0$.

> **3-13 Theorem.** Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $g:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a 1-1, continuously differentiable function such that $\det g'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in A$. If $f: g(A)\to\mathbb{R}$ is integrable, then $$\int_{g(A)}f=\int_A(f\circ g)|\det g'|.$$

> **3-14. Theorem (Sard's Theorem).** Let $g:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable, where $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open, and let $B=\{x\in A:\det g'(x)=0\}$. Then $g(B)$ has measure $0$.